# Incluir Host en una linea con awk

Tags: bash, script, ip, awk

Estoy intentando guardar con un script en bash la ip de mi equipo en un archivo .env para realizar una configuración automática dentro del un docker-compose

Dicho archivo tiene que tener este formato dentro.

```
HOST=192.168.0.0
```

Con esta linea logro esta respuesta y guardarlo en el archivo .env

```
ip addr show enp0s3 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1 > /home/user/.env
```

**Repuesta** 
192.168.0.22

Pero por mas que he intentado agregar el "host=" para incluir en el archivo .env no doy con ello

La respuesta de la linea dentro del archivo .env debería ser

```
host=192.168.0.0
```

Alguna idea ?

Gracias de antemano.. !!! :)

Comment: ¿Cuál es la salida exacta de `ip addr show enp0s3`? Porque seguramente con Awk solo ya habría suficiente

Answer (score 3):

Modifica AWK con esto:

```
awk {'print "HOST="$2'}
```

Comment: Tal cual no me funciono, pero siguiendo tu ejemplo lo he puesto tal que así awk '{print"host=" $2}'  y ha funcionado correctamente.. !!!! Millones de gracias.. !!!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
echo HOST="$(ip addr show enp0s3 | grep -Po 'inet\s+\K(\d+\.?){4}')" > /home/user/.env
```

O, con el uso de `xargs`:

```
ip addr show enp0s3 \
 | grep -Po 'inet\s+\K(\d+\.?){4}' \
 | xargs -I % echo HOST="%" > /home/user/.env
```

Lo que hago es utilizar una expresión regular para obtener la dirección sin necesidad de llamar mas programas como `awk`, `cut`, etc. Luego el resultado lo pongo en un *command substitution* que lo imprimo como valor de la variable `HOST`.

Si quieres ver la salida de este comando, sólo copia y pega el `echo` sin la redirección.

Es decir:

```
echo HOST="$(ip addr show enp0s3 | grep -Po 'inet\s+\K(\d+\.?){4}')"
```

En mi caso obtengo: `192.168.1.69`.

Uso `grep -Po` para habilitar las expresiones regulares tipo Perl y que sólo muestre lo emparejado con la expresión. Lo que hace la expresión regular `inet\s+\K(\d+\.?){4}` es:

- `inet\s+`: marca lo que tenga `inet` seguido de uno o mas (`+`) espacios (`\s`),
- `\K`: luego lo "olvida", es decir, le indica al motor que pretenda que inició desde ahí (después del emparejamiento anterior),
- `(\d+\.?){4}`: busca que se repita cuatro veces (`{4}`) el siguiente patrón: `<mas de un dígito><punto opcional>` que corresponde a, por ejemplo, `192.168.1.69`. Esto del punto opcional es por el caso del último emparejamiento de una dirección IP v4 que no lleva punto; es decir, tomando mi ejemplo, `192.` *si* lleva punto al final, también `168.`, y así hasta `69` que **no** tiene punto final; por eso es opcional que el patrón termine con un punto.

#### Nota sobre `xargs`.

Lo que hago con `xargs` es sencillo. La salida del comando anterior (la dirección emparejada con la expresión regular) la uso con el *placeholder* "%", es decir, donde esté el caracter "%" se usara la salida del comando anterior (en este caso, la dirección). Y eso se lo paso a `echo HOST="%"`, luego redirecciono al archivo deseado.

Yo preferiría la aproximación con `xargs` porque soy un jodido huevón y no me gusta la idea de escribir `echo HOST=$(` y luego copiar y pegar el *pipeine*. O el otro caso donde escribas el comando, luego escribas `)"` para cerrar el *command substitution*, luego des "CTRL + a" para ir al inicio y poner `echo HOST="$(` para completarlo. Con `xargs` al menos me siento entre mas productivo y mas *pro*.

Es cuestión de gustos, pero el resultado es el mismo. Digo, quizás es sub-utilizar `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
ip addr show enp0s3 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print"Host="$2}' | cut -d/ -f1 > /home/user/.env
```